# Override a method for each instance of a class in Java

Tags: java

I created a class `Action` and a class `Person`, so each `Person` has many actions it can do. I want each instance of `Action` class to have a different version of the method `Action.Execute`. 
How can I do that in Java?

```
public class Action
{

  public String Identifier;
  public String[] Identifiers;

  public Action(String Inpt)
  {
     this.Identifier = Inpt;
  }

  public void Execute()
  {
     System.out.println("Template Empty");
  }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this (I know it does not make sense, but I want you to understand the idea):

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Action a = new Action("X");
       a 
       {
           public void Execute()
           {
               //do something diferent
           }
       }

       Action b = new Action("J");
       b
       {
           public void Execute()
           {
            //do something ELSE
           }
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: you can use an interface

Answer (score 1):

you can use `method overriding`  [method overriding javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) concept like below :-

```
 public abstract class Action {

    public String Identifier;
    public String[] Identifiers;

    public Action(String Inpt) {
        this.Identifier = Inpt;
    }

    protected abstract void Execute();
}

class HumanAction extends Action {

    public HumanAction(String Inpt) {
        super(Inpt);
    }

    @Override
    public void Execute() {
        System.out.println("human action");
    }
}

class AnimalAction extends Action {
    public AnimalAction(String Inpt) {
        super(Inpt);
    }

    @Override
    public void Execute() {
        System.out.println("animal action");
    }
}
```

Now in your test class :-

```
    public class ActionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HumanAction hu = new HumanAction("X");
        hu.Execute();

        AnimalAction animal = new AnimalAction("X");
        animal.Execute();


    }
}
```

O/p of which will be below :-

> human action
> animal action

EDIT :- Added proper example with runnable code.

Comment: I can not provide runabble example because it does not run, the problem of using abstract classes and Interfaces is that i will have maybe thousands of "Actions" so then I would need to write thousands of Children Classes

Comment: @VíctorEduardoAvilésRomo , its not the case, you just define all the actions abstract or with minimum implementation and in this case you don't need to have another action class for each action, only class which needs to enhance or change the default behaviour, they need to implement or extend the class, thats the recommended way in OOPS programming.

Comment: @VíctorEduardoAvilésRomo , let me know if this solved your issue or not ?

Comment: Well it is a way to do it, I just was wondering if there was a way to just overwrite the method with out create a new class for each one cause it seems caothic to me to manage between thousands of class files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `Action` class abstract. Then create new subclasses for each action, eg `Run`, `Walk`, `Swim`.

```
public abstract class Action {
    abstract void execute();
}

public class Run extends Action {
    @Override
    void execute() {
         System.out.println("Running");
    }
}

public class Swim extends Action {
    @Override
    void execute() {
         System.out.println("Swimming");
    }
}
```

If you want to go further you can use the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), and then pass the `Action` to the `Person` class:

```
public abstract class Action {
    abstract void execute(Person person);
}

public class Run extends Action {

    @Override
    void execute(Person person) {
         System.out.println(person.getName()+" is running");
    }

}
```

then in your `Person` class:

```
public void executeAction(Action action) {
    action.execute(this);
}
```

giving:

```
Action action = new Run();
myPerson.executeAction(action);
```

Meaning that the `Person` doesn't need to know how to swim, walk or run, it is all contained within the `Action` class that 'visits' it.

Comment: mmm that works, the problem is that  I will have maybe thousands of "Actions" so if I use abstract classes or Interfaces I would need to write thousands of Children Classes. I was wondering if there was another way to just overwrite the Method

Comment: Yes, there is.  I'll post an answer if I have time later.  But yes, you can override just the method, without declaring a whole new class.  There are [some examples here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: Thank you, that yould be really useful